# How to add layers of hexagons?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw the following figure.

[image]

But, I only managed to add a layer of hexagons. How to control the addition of other layers?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{tikz}
        
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{center}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        x=7.5mm,y=4.34mm,
        box/.style={
            regular polygon,
            regular polygon sides=6,     
            minimum size=10mm,       
            inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm,
            draw}
        ]
        \node [box,fill=black] (innerbox) {};

        \foreach [evaluate=\x as \y using {int(ifthenelse(\x+2>6,\x-4,\x+2))}] \x in {1,...,6}

        \node [box,anchor=corner \y] at (innerbox.corner \x) {};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps this post could be helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/579894/drawing-hexagonal-lattice-with-paths-marked-with-dark-black-and-its-midedges

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277920/how-to-paint-a-ring-of-hexagons

Comment: https://www.latexstudio.net/index/details/index/mid/2353

Comment: https://www.latexstudio.net/index/details/index/mid/2355

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first image done simply with Mathcha: https://www.mathcha.io/editor

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,300); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 300

%Shape: Regular Polygon [id:dp9566546074648377] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (275,119) -- (296.65,131.5) -- (296.65,156.5) -- (275,169) -- (253.35,156.5) -- (253.35,131.5) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Regular Polygon [id:dp4486958110204873] 
\draw  [line width=1.5]  (253.35,156.5) -- (275,169) -- (275,194) -- (253.35,206.5) -- (231.7,194) -- (231.7,169) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Regular Polygon [id:dp6000238577265022] 
\draw  [line width=1.5]  (318.3,119) -- (339.95,131.5) -- (339.95,156.5) -- (318.3,169) -- (296.65,156.5) -- (296.65,131.5) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Regular Polygon [id:dp915351643892887] 
\draw  [line width=1.5]  (296.65,156.5) -- (318.3,169) -- (318.3,194) -- (296.65,206.5) -- (275,194) -- (275,169) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Regular Polygon [id:dp5987225724596497] 
\draw  [line width=1.5]  (296.65,81.5) -- (318.3,94) -- (318.3,119) -- (296.65,131.5) -- (275,119) -- (275,94) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Regular Polygon [id:dp8189916716968941] 
\draw  [line width=1.5]  (231.7,119) -- (253.35,131.5) -- (253.35,156.5) -- (231.7,169) -- (210.05,156.5) -- (210.05,131.5) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Regular Polygon [id:dp4670606738503664] 
\draw  [line width=1.5]  (361.6,119) -- (383.25,131.5) -- (383.25,156.5) -- (361.6,169) -- (339.95,156.5) -- (339.95,131.5) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Regular Polygon [id:dp5621437109282943] 
\draw  [line width=1.5]  (188.4,119) -- (210.05,131.5) -- (210.05,156.5) -- (188.4,169) -- (166.75,156.5) -- (166.75,131.5) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Regular Polygon [id:dp6599968429743048] 
\draw  [line width=1.5]  (210.05,81.5) -- (231.7,94) -- (231.7,119) -- (210.05,131.5) -- (188.4,119) -- (188.4,94) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Regular Polygon [id:dp5494891870772345] 
\draw  [line width=1.5]  (253.35,81.5) -- (275,94) -- (275,119) -- (253.35,131.5) -- (231.7,119) -- (231.7,94) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Regular Polygon [id:dp7594270518236381] 
\draw  [line width=1.5]  (339.95,81.5) -- (361.6,94) -- (361.6,119) -- (339.95,131.5) -- (318.3,119) -- (318.3,94) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Regular Polygon [id:dp7542566297595752] 
\draw  [line width=1.5]  (210.05,156.5) -- (231.7,169) -- (231.7,194) -- (210.05,206.5) -- (188.4,194) -- (188.4,169) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Regular Polygon [id:dp13329549779333316] 
\draw  [line width=1.5]  (339.95,156.5) -- (361.6,169) -- (361.6,194) -- (339.95,206.5) -- (318.3,194) -- (318.3,169) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Regular Polygon [id:dp2175531439213112] 
\draw  [line width=1.5]  (231.7,194) -- (253.35,206.5) -- (253.35,231.5) -- (231.7,244) -- (210.05,231.5) -- (210.05,206.5) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Regular Polygon [id:dp18515279548847507] 
\draw  [line width=1.5]  (275,194) -- (296.65,206.5) -- (296.65,231.5) -- (275,244) -- (253.35,231.5) -- (253.35,206.5) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Regular Polygon [id:dp05008914090789984] 
\draw  [line width=1.5]  (318.3,194) -- (339.95,206.5) -- (339.95,231.5) -- (318.3,244) -- (296.65,231.5) -- (296.65,206.5) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Regular Polygon [id:dp7243060183264154] 
\draw  [line width=1.5]  (231.7,44) -- (253.35,56.5) -- (253.35,81.5) -- (231.7,94) -- (210.05,81.5) -- (210.05,56.5) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Regular Polygon [id:dp20654389275063734] 
\draw  [line width=1.5]  (275,44) -- (296.65,56.5) -- (296.65,81.5) -- (275,94) -- (253.35,81.5) -- (253.35,56.5) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Regular Polygon [id:dp7883357127939892] 
\draw  [line width=1.5]  (318.3,44) -- (339.95,56.5) -- (339.95,81.5) -- (318.3,94) -- (296.65,81.5) -- (296.65,56.5) -- cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sebastião, Show!!

Comment: @BeneditoFreire You're welcome :-))))))))))

Answer (score 4):

Purely for comparison, here is an alternative using [Metapost](https://tug.org/metapost.html), some loops, and some colour.

[image]

Change the `rings` variable to control how many rings (or layers) of hexagons are added.  Change the colours to suit, or just remove the fill line, if you don't want colour.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
input colorbrewer-rgb
beginfig(1);
    path h; 
    h = for i=0 upto 5: 17 up rotated 60i -- endfor cycle;
    pair u, v;
    u = point 2 of h - point 0 of h;
    v = u rotated 120;
    numeric rings;  rings = 5;
    for i = 0 upto 5:
        for j = 1 upto rings:
            for k = 0 upto j - 1:
                path t; t = h shifted (j * u + k * v) rotated 60i;
                fill t withcolor Oranges[8][j];
                draw t;
            endfor
        endfor
    endfor
    fill h;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

This is wrapped up in `luamplib`, so you need to compile it with the `lualatex` engine.

Comment: I not use metapost that I not know :-/. Excellent answer.