# How use tikz to draw hive

Tags: tikz-pgf, polygon

I want to draw following picture

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{paper}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide,amsmath} 
\usetkzobj{all} 

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\unitlength}{0.20mm}


\begin{tikzpicture}

% green
\node[regular polygon,draw, regular polygon sides = 6,fill=green!60!black](g) at (6,0) {};
% brown
\tkzDefPoint(6,0){O} \tkzDefPoint(6.26,0.152){A}
\tkzDefPointsBy[rotation=center O angle 360/6](A,B,C,D,E){B,C,D,E,F}
\foreach \a in {A,B,C,D,E,F} { %\a is the angle variable
   \node[regular polygon,draw, regular polygon sides = 6,fill=brown!70!black,](c\a) at (\a) 
{};
}
%blue
\tkzDefPoint(6,0){O} \tkzDefPoint(6.45,.45){b1}
\tkzDefPointsBy[rotation=center O angle 360/3](b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10,b11) 
{b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10,b11,b12}
\foreach \a in {b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10,b11,b12} { %\a is the angle variable
    \node[regular polygon,draw, regular polygon sides = 6,fill=blue!30!white](b\a) at (\a) {};
}


\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

And I get following output

[image]

I have also this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\newcommand{\hexcoord}[2]
{[shift=(0:#1),shift=(60:#1),shift=(0:#2),shift=(-60:#2)]}


\draw[fill=green]\hexcoord{0}{0}
(0:1)--(60:1)--(120:1)--(180:1)--(-120:1)--(-60:1)--cycle;

\draw\hexcoord{0}{1}
(0:1)--(60:1)--(120:1)--(180:1)--(-120:1)--(-60:1)--cycle;
\draw\hexcoord{1}{0}
(0:1)--(60:1)--(120:1)--(180:1)--(-120:1)--(-60:1)--cycle;
\draw\hexcoord{1}{-1}
(0:1)--(60:1)--(120:1)--(180:1)--(-120:1)--(-60:1)--cycle;
\draw\hexcoord{0}{-1}
(0:1)--(60:1)--(120:1)--(180:1)--(-120:1)--(-60:1)--cycle;
\draw\hexcoord{-1}{0}
(0:1)--(60:1)--(120:1)--(180:1)--(-120:1)--(-60:1)--cycle;
\draw\hexcoord{-1}{1}
(0:1)--(60:1)--(120:1)--(180:1)--(-120:1)--(-60:1)--cycle;





\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

I think the following coordinates are useful.

[image]

Comment: Can I have a p please Bob?

Comment: rather similar to this one:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/633946/15036

Do the answers to that one help?

Answer (score 10):

This implements a `hexaring` coordinate system with the parameters `ring` (counting from 0) and `pos` (also counting from 0) where `pos` specifies the hexagons per ring, i.e. on ring 1 exists the positions 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. These parameters are used to calculate a positions in the *xy* coordinate system for hexagons described in a circumference of radius 1.

The outer loops in `\tikzhexagonofhexagons` goes through all rings in the given list and for each ring the inner loop gooes through all positions.

For each position the hexagon will be drawn with the key `hexagon = {<ring>}{<pos>}`. This key also applies a key for each ring and each position as well as keys for each sides and each position on a side.
If necessary, all these keys also have access to the ring number `#1` and/or the pos number `#2`.

These keys can now be adjusted so that each hexagon can look differently.

Some examples can be seen below.

---

Maybe using a separate coordinate system isn't optimal since the calculation in the last example (`int(<pos>/<ring>)`) is already done by the coordinate system to determine the position on the ring but I like to separate my tasks.

The coordinate `(hexagon cs: ring = <ring>, pos = <pos>)` is equivalent to

```
($({30+int(\pos/\ring)*60}:1.73205*\ring)
  !mod(\pos,\ring)/\ring!
  ({90+int(\pos/\ring)*60}:1.73205*\ring)$)
```

with the `calc` library.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepgfkeyslibrary{ext.pgfkeys-plus}
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{hexaring}{%
  \pgfqkeys{/tikz/cs}{#1}%
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\hRing{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cs/ring}}%
  \ifnum\hRing=0 \pgfpointorigin
  \else
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\hPos{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cs/pos}}%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\hSide{\hPos/\hRing}%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\hPosOnSide{mod(\hPos,\hRing)}%
    \pgfpointlineattime{\hPosOnSide/\hRing}
      {\pgfpointpolarxy{30+\hSide*60}{1.73205*\hRing}}
      {\pgfpointpolarxy{90+\hSide*60}{1.73205*\hRing}}%
  \fi}
\tikzset{
  cs/ring/.initial=0, cs/pos/.initial=0, list/.initial={0,...,4},
  hexagon path/.style 2 args={
    insert path={plot[sharp cycle,samples at={0, 60, ..., 359}](\x:1)}},
  hexagon/.style 2 args={
    hexagon ring #1/.try={#2}, hexagon pos #2/.try={#1},
    /utils/TeX/ifnum={#1=0}{}{
      hexagon not ring 0/.try={#1}{#2},
      style/.pgfmath wrap={hexagon side ##1/.try={#1}{#2}}{int(#2/#1)},
      style/.pgfmath wrap={hexagon pos' ##1/.try={#1}{#2}}{int(mod(#2,#1))}}}}
\newcommand*\tikzhexagonofhexagons[1][]{%
  \foreach[/utils/exec=\tikzset{#1}, expand list,
           evaluate={\hexPerRing=int(max(1,\ring*6)-1);}]\ring in{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/list}}
    \foreach[/tikz/cs/ring=\ring]\pos in {0, ..., \hexPerRing}
      \draw[hexagon={\ring}{\pos}, shift={(hexaring cs: pos=\pos)}, hexagon path={\ring}{\pos}];}
\begin{document}
\tikz[
  x=.5cm, y=.5cm, column sep=7mm,
  set ring color/.style args={#1=#2}{hexagon ring #1/.append style={fill={#2}}},
  set side color/.style args={#1=#2}{hexagon side #1/.append style={fill={#2}}},
  set pos  color/.style args={#1=#2}{hexagon pos  #1/.append style={fill={#2}}},
  set pos' color/.style args={#1=#2}{hexagon pos' #1/.append style={fill={#2}}},
  set center color/.style={hexagon ring 0/.append style={fill={#1}}},
]\matrix{
  \tikzhexagonofhexagons[
    set ring color/.list={
      0=green!25, 1=pink, 2=blue!25, 3=yellow!50, 4=magenta!50}]
& \tikzhexagonofhexagons[
    x=.4cm, y=.4cm, list={1, 3, 5},
    hexagon path/.style={draw=none, insert path={circle[radius=cos 30]}},
    hexagon/.append style={
      fill/.pgfmath if={iseven(#2)}{green!50}{magenta!50}}]
& \tikzhexagonofhexagons[
    set side color/.list={
      0=green!25, 1=pink, 2=blue!25, 3=yellow!50, 4=magenta!50, 5=orange!50},
    set center color=gray]
& \tikzhexagonofhexagons[
    set pos' color/.list={
      0=green!25, 1=pink, 2=blue!25, 3=yellow!50, 4=magenta!50, 5=orange!50},
    set center color=orange]
& \tikzhexagonofhexagons[
    rotate=-30, list = {1, ..., 4},
    hexagon not ring 0/.style 2 args={
      fill/.pgfmath wrap={blue!##1!magenta}{100*#2/\hexPerRing}}]
\\};
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: That is excellent.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, let's see. Analysis and one route to your solution.

1st, we like MWE's, which means: removing all that's not needed to show your solution. That's why you'll see many packages being disabled below.

2nd, tkz-euclide can be used here, but isn't really needed. All can be done with ordinary Tikz.

3rd, looks like you mixed up angles: a) to specify a polar coordinate, b) to rotate something. Rotation isn't needed here.

4th, using the regular shape is tempting. However, its inner radius is variable, i.e. depends on the text you put `\node [] {blow up radius};`, which makes specifying coordinates difficult (see pgfmanual). So I decided to draw a `\pic` called `hv` instead, with a defined outer radius r=1. (You can do it in tkz-euclide as well).

5th, placement strategy of hives. For the varius radial layers I suggest doing 2 things: a) place first hive, which can be replicated in 60-deg increments, b) place second one etc., until all starters are placed. You need 1 starter for the first layer, two for the second and so on, like so:

```
    % ~~~ middle ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    %\node[pol,fill=green!60!black] at (0,0) {};% PROBLEM: node readius varies, undetermined !
    \pic at (0,0) {hv=green!60!black};
    % ~~~ first layer ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \foreach \w in {30,90,...,330}  \pic at (\w:1.73)   {hv=brown!70!black};    % r = 2 * cos(30)
    % ~~~ second layer ~~~~~~~~~~
    \foreach \w in {0,60,...,300}   \pic at (\w:3)      {hv=white};             % r = 3 * cos(0)        
    \foreach \w in {30,90,...,330}  \pic at (\w:3.46)   {hv=blue!30!white};     % r = 4 * cos(30)
```

For simplicity I calculated the polar radii by hand; feel free to make tikz calculate them for you. There's a help layer at the end, drawn over everything, to make finding coordinates of the starters a breeze. Extend it when you add layers.

6th, about the `pic` `hv`. It needs to accept one parameter, the fill-color drawn. So it turned out that it's best to define it as a code-block:

```
\tikzset{
    pics/hv/.style n args={1}{
        code={
            \draw[fill=#1] (0:1) foreach \w in {60,120,...,360} { -- (\w:1)};% outer radius is 1 now
             \node at (0,0) {x}; % DIDATICS: just indicating the center
        }
    }
}
```

This means, instead of calling `\pic at (0,0) {hv};` as usual for pics, you'll pass the parameters at the end, like `{hv=white};`. Passing nothing fills the hive with black (you can define default options, if needed).

To make the starters of a layer more evident I used different colors, which you simply can replace.

7th, the next layers should be easy to create now. Finally remove all my `DIDATICS` code ;-)

8th, for more flexibility you may want to turn the whole final tikzpicture into a pic, like `bighive/.pic={ ... }` as a format statement or tikzset. Then you can place bighive's more easily. For scaling please check `scale` and `transform shape` in the pgfmanual: you may need both of them.

[image: result]

```
%\documentclass[]{paper}
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{fouriernc}
%\usepackage{tkz-euclide,amsmath} 
%\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
%\usetkzobj{all} 
%
%\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    pics/hv/.style n args={1}{
        code={
            \draw[fill=#1] (0:1) foreach \w in {60,120,...,360} { -- (\w:1)};% outer radius is 1 now
             \node at (0,0) {x}; % DIDATICS: just indicating the center
        }
    }
}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    %pol/.style={regular polygon,draw,regular polygon sides=6}
    ]
    % ~~~ middle ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    %\node[pol,fill=green!60!black] at (0,0) {};% PROBLEM: node readius varies, undetermined !
    \pic at (0,0) {hv=green!60!black};
    % ~~~ first layer ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \foreach \w in {30,90,...,330}  \pic at (\w:1.73)   {hv=brown!70!black};    % r = 2 * cos(30)
    % ~~~ second layer ~~~~~~~~~~
    \foreach \w in {0,60,...,300}   \pic at (\w:3)      {hv=white};             % r = 3 * cos(0)        
    \foreach \w in {30,90,...,330}  \pic at (\w:3.46)   {hv=blue!30!white};     % r = 4 * cos(30)   

    \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (4,4);% DIDATICS
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: can we write for an arbitrary n. that we put 1, 2,3 etc. and get each of them?

Comment: Right. If you want 3 parameters, you write `args={3}` and use #1, #2 and #3 inside. See Ch. 87.4.3 Defining Key Codes in the pfgmanual.

Comment: Following question is useful. How can write for an arbitrary number?https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/688260/how-atomatically-draw-hiv-using-tikz